# ios how to change another view controller's content in different view controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift and ios developer. And I want to create a side menu that the cell event will dynamically change the content in a container view. But it seems not work.

[the left is the tableview(my side menu) and the right is the container view with a viewcontroller(vc2) on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63ptc.png)

I try two ways to change background color of the container view

the first is

```
    func tableView (_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

    let vc2 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vc2")  as? ViewController2

    vc2?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white      

    }
```

and the second way is

```
    func tableView (_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

    let vc2 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vc2")  as? ViewController2

    vc2?.changecolor()


    }
```

and in vc2

```
func changecolor()
{
    print(123)
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple

}
```

it will print 123 but not change bg color

How can I change the content in other view controller ? (If I don't want to remove the current container view and change to another one)

Comment: It is the same situation with a segue: when you perform segue, UI elements (as IBOutlets) of destination are not yet set, so you cannot change them. That's why you need to set a property in destination and use this property after loading, or at viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear time.

Comment: @claude31 But my vc2 is above the table view.I just push the x position of what above the table view to right.Didn’t the vc2 load already?(I can also click the bar item on it)

Comment: Don't understand : in didSelectRow, you instantiate the VC2. Why, if it is already there ?

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView (_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

let vc2 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vc2")  as? ViewController2

vc2?.setColor(UIColor.purple)


}

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    private(set) var color:UIColor?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        guard let color = self.color else { return }
        self.view.backgroundColor = color
    }

    func setColor(_ color:UIColor) {
        self.color = color
    }
}
```